# group contents inside td element

Tags: html, css

let's say I have something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
           <span class="text_1">Text 1</span>
           <span class="text_2">Text 2</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I tell each `span` inside my `td` to take 50% of the width of my `td` and also center align the text of my span? I also want the texts to appear next to each other on the same line inside my td. I tried something like on the spans:

```
...
<span class="text_1" style="display:inline-block;width:50%;">Text 1</span>
<span class="text_2" style="display:inline-block;width:50%;">Text 2</span>
...
```

But that didn't work

Thank you

Comment: Why use tables? Use divs instead.

Comment: span is an inline element. Setting a width won't work. Better use divs for that.

Comment: I'd suggest giving the td a width too so it has something to inherit 50% from. If that doesn't do it, try giving tr and table fixed widths too.

Comment: `inline-block` allows an element to take a `width` (edited to correct my stupidity/typo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will each take 50% of the width of the parent element, the problem is the newline between the elements that *also* takes up a portion of that space. 50% + a space + 50% equals *more* than 100%.

Remove the new-line, or use `float: left` (or `right`).

With `float: left`: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Vcduz/).

Without the new-line: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Vcduz/1/).

Comment: Can you give me an example of the one that uses float left but using divs instead of span (without using display inline block?

Comment: Why? If you use `div` elements, with the same CSS, they'll behave exactly the same.

Comment: If I don't use `display:inline-block;`, it doesn't work. I would like to try to stay away from using it because it causes problems in IE

Comment: If you use `float: left` you don't *need* to use `display: inline-block` a `div` can *already* take a width, after all: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Vcduz/2/).

Comment: `<div class="text_1" style="text-align:center;float:left;width:50%;">Text 1</div>`, `<div class="text_2" style="text-align:center;width:50%;">Text 2</div>` does not work. Text 1 does not float to the left, they are displayed vertically

Comment: Then produce a demo that reproduces your problem.